# Facebook shows news feed messages that aren't returned by any of the APIs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-feed

I noticed that my feedback news feed shows certain posts that aren't returned by any of the API's.  (I tried the GraphAPI and the legacy REST API and FQL).

I can see those status updates at http://facebook.com on my news feed and I can also see them in the Facebook mobile app on iPhone and the mobile app on Windows Mobile.

Some of my friends seem to have set a privacy setting.  I think it is this one: "How people bring your info to apps they use" - decheck "My Status Updates", although I can't confirm that is the only reason their posts don't show up, it seems one possible explanation.

So, what API are these facebook mobile applications using which returns the same data as the web site ? Is it possible for me to build another facebook client using that API?

Answer (score 0):

Have you acquired the read_stream extended permission?  This is required to see all postings.  Typically without it you don't see any posts, but I think you can see posts that are marked as being completely public.

Comment: Yes

http : // www .facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri= http : // www. facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=touch&scope=read_stream,read_mailbox

Comment: *"I don't have enough reputation to comment"* **does not mean that you should use an Answer instead**.  It means that you need to learn how to use the site, and when you are sufficiently experienced, you will be granted the [privilege](/help/privileges) of commenting.  Until then, please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: @TobySpeight - are you a bot?  This happened 6 years ago...  You might want to limit these helpful tips to posts that happened somewhat recently.

Comment: Yeah, Review often asks us to look at posts of different ages. As this is the only answer to the question, it may well be worth improving it to be a complete answer, so still worth commenting.  And no, I don't think I'm a bot (at least, last time I looked!).

Comment: Okay, I removed the sentence that was troublesome